# Is there a counterpart to "CreateInstance"?

Tags: com, msxml, destruction

We have some code that uses MSXML, and does this to create the XML document object:

```
MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocumentPtr  doc_in;

doc_in.CreateInstance("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0");
```

Once we're finished with doc_in, how do we destroy it? Is it just automatically destructed when doc_in goes out of scope, or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

COM object lifetime management builds on [reference counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) via [`IUnknown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680509%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)s methods `AddRef()` and `Release()`. For details see *["Using and Implementing IUnknown"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693423%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)*, in particular *["Rules for Managing Reference Counts"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms692481%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)*.

On top of that smart pointers are used, most commonly ATLs [`CComPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezzw7k98%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)/[`CComQIPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc177dxw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [`_com_ptr_t`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/417w8b3b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

So, if you're dealing with a plain pointer to a COM instance, you have to `Release()` manually to relinquish ownership.
If you have a smart pointer to a COM instance, the `Release()` should be done for you when the smart pointer instance goes out of scope - but to be sure take a look at the documentation for the actual smart pointer class you are using.

Answer (score 3):

If *IXMLDOMDocumentPtr* is a smart pointer (as it looks like) then it will take care of calling doc_in.Release() for you.

Comment: What if I was using a `IXMLDOMDocument *` instead of an `IXMLDOMDocumentPtr `? Would that mean a different answer? I'm trying to get my head around COM...

Comment: Sure. In COM you are responsible for tracking COM interface usage. For  that you use AddRef() and Release() calls on the interface pointer. If you are using "raw" pointers you need to call Release() when you are not using the pointer any more (not that AddRef() will be called for whoever handled the pointer to you - for instance QueryInterface()).